# Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы любые изображения рисовались на экране в пределах определённой фигуры?

Tags: opengl, libgdx

Здравствуйте! Пишу на LibGDX и столкнулся с такой проблемой. Нужно сделать так, чтобы все элементы рисовались внутри определённой фигуры на экране и всё, что за неё вылезает - обрезалось. Знаю про ScissorStack и про glScissor, но они, к сожалению, обрезают только прямоугольник, у которого не меняется угол. Можно ли как-нибудь решить эту проблему?

Comment: Уточните: Шейдеры можете использовать для этого? Фигура задается текстурой, плоской геометрией, объемной геометрией?

Comment: Все фигуры плоские, 2D, по поводу шейдеров не знаю, как они работают. Нашёл решение в виде glStencil, но абсолютно не понял систему и как с ним работать. Подскажите, как и что лучше использовать, чтобы не затратно (так как при каждом рендере используется). Заранее спасибо

Comment: Стенсил тоже вариант, если поддерживается на целевых устройствах. Выбирайте сами, шейдерами или стенсилом. Ну или 3й вариант рисовать все как есть и сверху с отключенным тестом глубины рисовать выворотку фигуры.

Comment: Я прочёл про шейдеры, кажется затратным расчёт каждого пикселя по вершинам, плюс требуется язык GLSL, а создавать текст шейдера программно - тоже некрасиво. Наверное, самый лучший вариант - это тест глубины. Расскажите, пожалуйста, как им пользоваться, я прочёл много статей, но понимания, как заполнить определённую фигуру, так и не пришло. Буду пресного благодарен